# Confused about proper location of SQLite database in relation to a Core Data model

Tags: ios, sqlite

Is it okay to store a SQLite database within the app bundle and read data from there, or does one have to move the database to e.g. the cache folder or documents folder?

I am concerned that my app will be rejected if i do not comply with the storage guidelines..

By default i see that the DB within the simulator is located at : .. data/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/StorageTest.sqlite

That would be the default documents folder right? Is it okay to take the database and move it to the bundle? I have heard on some occasions where larger files within the documents folder caused applications to be rejected.

The data is not generated by the user, and is required for the application to function properly.

As it may appear from my question, i am really confused about the location of the sqlite database.

Furthermore, if it turns out that it is okay to store the read-only database within the bundle, then how can i specify an entity related to another sqlite database within the documents folder? To e.g. write user specific settings etc. I suppose it is specified within the app delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the Documents folder is that it's supposed to contain data that could only be generated by the user, given that it's going to be synchronized with iCloud. Have a look at the [guidelines for data storage](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html).

In your case the bundle should be alright then, given that, from what I understood, it's fixed data and not ephemeral (candidates for the cache or tmp folders).

Regarding how to interact with the custom database, I would suggest to give a look at [core data and how to handle the persistent store.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html)